# Computing an 'odd' determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

I'm wondering how to compute an 'odd' determinant:

${D_n} = \det \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  {{a_n}}&x&x& \cdots &x \\ 
  y&{{a_{n - 1}}}&x& \cdots &x \\ 
  y&y&{{a_{n - 2}}}&x& \vdots  \\ 
   \vdots & \vdots &y& \ddots &x \\ 
  y&y& \cdots &y&{{a_1}} 
\end{array}} \right]$

I tried Laplace expansion but still couldn't get a clue...

Also I wonder if there is a 'neat' expression for the result...

Any help will be appreciated:)

Comment: Any reason to believe a nice result even exists?

Comment: It seems to be related with symmetric polynomials of the coefficients $a_i$'s and homogenous polynomials of $x$ and $y$... My friend told me it's an exercise so ... maybe there is a nice result :)

Comment: Put $${B_n} = \det \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  {{y}}&x&x& \cdots &x \\ 
  y&{{a_{n - 1}}}&x& \cdots &x \\ 
  y&y&{{a_{n - 2}}}&x& \vdots  \\ 
   \vdots & \vdots &y& \ddots &x \\ 
  y&y& \cdots &y&{{a_1}} 
\end{array}} \right]$$ then $D_n=(a_n-y)D_{n-1}-(x-a_{n-1})B_{n-1}$ and $B_{n-1}=(a_{n-2}-x)B_{n-2}$. Not sure how helpful that might be!

Comment: Let $f(\lambda) = \prod\limits_{k=1}^n (a_k - \lambda)$, we have
$\det D_n = \frac{yf(x)-xf(y)}{y-x}$
. See answers of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1801627/59379) for a proof.