# Calculate the determinant, expanding the sum of the determinants:

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, matrix-equations

$$ A = \begin{vmatrix}
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & \dots & 1 \\
1 & a_1 & x & x &\dots & x \\
1 & y & a_2 & x & \dots & x \\
1 & y & y & a_3 & \dots & x\\
\cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots \\
1 & y & y & y &\dots& a_n
\end{vmatrix}$$

as we define: $\ f(x) = (a_1-x)(a_2-x) \cdots (a_n-x), \ f(y) = (a_1 -y)(a_2 -y) \cdots (a_n -y) $

**Prove that**: $det(A) = \frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}$

It isn't very clear how to get an answer. Help me please.

Comment: There is no $f(x)$, $f(y)$, $f(z)$ or $z$ in your determinant. Are you looking at the right answer for the question asked??

Comment: @Paul I believe he defines the function $f(x)$ as $(a_1-x)\cdots(a_n-x)$ for convenience.

Comment: @YourongZang, Yes

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Suggest change the comma to "where.."

Comment: A similar approach as here https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1801627/42969 might work.

Comment: As Martin R mentions, this is an application of the formula in the linked question. Multiply the first row of $A$ by $x$ and the first column by $y$, you may evaluate $xy\det(A)$ using that formula. Then cancel out the factor $xy$ to get the final result.