# Calculate a certain determinant as a limit – is this valid in an arbitrary field?

Tags: real-analysis, field-theory, determinant

Let $\mathbb{K}$ be a field, and $a,b,x_1,...,x_n\in \mathbb{K}$, we pose :

$$\Delta_n=\text{det} \left(\,\begin{bmatrix}x_1&a&\dots &a\\   b&x_2& \ddots  & \vdots\\ \vdots&\ddots&\ddots& a\\b&\dots&b& x_n\end{bmatrix}\,\right)$$

if $a\neq b$: $\Delta_n=\frac{b P(a)-a P(b)}{b-a}$, with $P(x)=\prod_i(x_i-x)$.

My problem is to calculate $\Delta_n$ in the case where $a=b$:

If $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{R}$: the function $x\to\frac{x P(a)-a P(x)}{x-a}$, is continuous in $\mathbb{R}$, then :
$$
\Delta_n=\lim_{x\to a}\frac{x P(a)-a P(x)}{x-a}=\lim_{x\to a}\frac{Q(x)-Q(a)}{x-a}=Q'(a)
$$
with $Q(x)=x P(a)-a P(x)$ and $Q'(x)=P(a)-a P'(x)=\prod_i(x_i-a)+a\sum_i\prod_{j\neq i}(x_i-a)$.

***Question:***

Can we say that this method is true for any field $\mathbb{K}$?

Comment: Just mentioning that the determinant (for $a \ne b$) is calculated here https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1801627/42969, and also on MathOverflow https://mathoverflow.net/q/264380/116247.

Comment: My problem is that this method I can apply it when $\mathbb{K}$ any field? that is to say, I can speak of the notion of continuity and of the notion of limit in all fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\Bbb K$ be a (commutative) field and fix $x_1, \ldots, x_n \in \Bbb K$. Denote the determinant with
$$
\Delta(a, b)= \begin{vmatrix}x_1&a&\dots &a\\   b&x_2& \ddots  & \vdots\\ \vdots&\ddots&\ddots& a\\b&\dots&b& x_n\end{vmatrix}
$$
for $a, b \in \Bbb K$, and let $P \in \Bbb K[x]$ be the polynomial $P(x) = (x_1-x) \ldots (x_n-x)$.

Then
$$
 (b-a)\Delta(a, b) = bP(a)-aP(b) = (b-a)P(a) - a (P(b)-P(a)) \\
 = (b-a) (P(a) - a Q(a, b))
$$
with $Q(a, b) = \frac{P(b)-P(a)}{b-a}$ in $\Bbb K[a, b]$. It follows that
$$
 \Delta(a, b) = P(a) - a Q(a, b)
$$
in $\Bbb K[a, b]$, and therefore
$$
 \Delta(a, a) = P(a) - a Q(a, a) = P(a) - a P'(a)
$$
where $P'$ is the [formal derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_derivative) of $P$, see in particular [Correspondence to analytic derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_derivative#Correspondence_to_analytic_derivative).

This confirms your result
$$
 \Delta(a, a) = P(a) - a P'(a) = \prod_i(x_i-a)+a\sum_i\prod_{j\neq i}(x_i-a)
$$
since the formal derivative in $\Bbb K[x]$ satisfies the usual sum and product rules for derivatives.